# MongoDB Composite Key query with one field unknown

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, composite-primary-key, composite-key

I have a database that has a unique combination of two fields (x and i) for every entry. So I have set the _id field to be {_id: {a: x, b: i}}. Now I want to retrieve all values that have a certain value x but that have any value for i.

Example:

```
  {_id: {a: 1, b: 5}},
  {_id: {a: 1, b: 3}},
  {_id: {a: 2, b: 5}}
  {_id: {a: 3, b: 3}}
```

Now I want to do something like: `db.find({_id: {a: 1, b: { $exists: true}})` or even easier: `db.find({_id: {a: 1})` that should return:

```
  {_id: {a: 1, b: 5}},
  {_id: {a: 1, b: 3}}
```

Is there any way I could achieve this? Or in other words can you query in any way on this composite primary key? Currently I added the fields to the object itself but this is not really an optimal solution as my data set gets really large.

**Edit:**

```
db.someCollection.find({"_id.a": 1, "_id.b": { $exists: true}})
```

Seems to be a solution, this is however just as slow as adding **a** as a field (not in the key) to the object. Is there a faster method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
db.someCollection.find({"_id.a": 1, "_id.b": { $exists: true}})
```

Comment: This seems to be equally slow as just not setting the values as a primary key but just as a database field. Is there any faster way to query this?

Comment: @JordenvanBreemen I think this is the only way to query a composite key. If I found I'll update here.